# Get the difference between two arraylist with duplicate elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to get the difference between two lists. And this is what I am doing.

```
oldList = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]
newList = [1,2,3,5]

List<Integer> add = new ArrayList<>(newList);
List<Integer> remove = new ArrayList<>(oldList);
add.removeAll(oldList);
remove.removeAll(newList);
```

The result I want

```
add = [5]
remove = [1,2,3,4,4]
```

But `removeAll()` remove all duplicate element. The results that I received

```
add = [5]
remove = [4,4]
```

How do I get the `add` and `remove` list? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to write some of your own code. This can't be done using only the Java Collection libraries alone.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyList<T> extends ArrayList<T>{

    public MyList(){
        super();
    }

    public void specialRemoveAll(T[] list) {
        for (T element : list) {
            remove(element); // This only removes the first entry that matches 'element', not all matches
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, if you don't care about speed, or anything the simplest and easiest to understand solution would be to add everything from each `List` to a `Set` since `Set`s can't have duplicate elements. Then iterate over the sets and build up the 2 results lists.

1. Iterate over oldList and add each element to oldSet
2. Iterate over newList and add each element to newSet
3. Iterate over oldSet - if item not in newSet, add item to removeList
4. Iterate over newSet - if item not in oldSet, add item to addList

That will solve your problem. It's not a single method built in to java,you'll have to make it yourself but it's very simple. It's not the most performant, but it's easy to understand.

Adding to sets removes duplicates. If it's not `old` but NOT `new`, that means it needs removed. If it's in `new` but not `old`, that means it needs added. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

```
oldList.removeIf(newList::remove);
List<Integer> add = new ArrayList<>(newList);
List<Integer> remove = new ArrayList<>(oldList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stream.of(oldList , newList )
                        .flatMap(List::stream).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());